# Merge sort algorithm in an array in C - .exe not running?

Tags: c, sorting, runtime-error, mergesort

The following is my 'C' code for MergeSort algorithm. I'm using Dev C++, using TDM:GCC compiler. Doesn't give compilation error but exe doesnt run after compilation. Please do help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int A[] = {12, 5, 6, 78, 223, 1, 45, 34, 78, 99};
    int n = sizeof(A);
    int i = 0;

    A[n] = MergeSort(A[n], n);

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf("%d\n", A[i]);

    return 0;
}

int MergeSort(int A[], int n)
{
    int mid = n/2;
    int left[mid], right[n - mid];
    int i;

    if(n<2) return;

    for ( i = 0; i < mid; i++ )
        left[i] = A[i];
    for ( i = mid; i < n; i++ )
        right[i] = A[i];

    int nL = sizeof(left);
    int nR = sizeof(right);

    MergeSort(left, nL);
    MergeSort(right, nR);
    Merge(left, right, nL, nR, mid);
}

int Merge(int left[], int right[], int nL, int nR, int mid)
{
    int n = nL + nR;
    int i, j, k = 0;
    int A[n];

    for ( k = 0; k < n; k++ )
    {
        if( left[i] <= right[mid + j] )
        {
            A[k] = left[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            A[k] = right[mid + j];
            j = j + 1;
        }

        if ( i + j >= n) break;
    }

    return;
}
```

My code doesn't run at all, and shows an error window instantaneously.

------ EDIT ------

My new edited code is as follows. No error now, but still the sorting doesn't take place.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int Merge(int left[], int right[], int nL, int nR, int A[])
{
    int n = nL + nR;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for ( k = 0; k < n; k++ )
    {
        if(i < nL && j < nR && left[i] <= right[j] )
        {
            A[k] = left[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            A[k] = right[j];
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }

    return;
}

void MergeSort(int A[], int n)
{
    int mid = n/2;
    int left[mid], right[n - mid];
    int i;

    if(n<=1) return;

    for ( i = 0; i < mid; i++ )
        left[i] = A[i];
    for ( i = 0; i < n - mid; i++ )
        right[i] = A[i + mid];

    int nL = sizeof(left)/sizeof(left[0]);
    int nR = sizeof(right)/sizeof(right[0]);

    MergeSort(left, nL);
    MergeSort(right, nR);
    Merge(left, right, nL, nR, A);
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = {98, 5, 6, 78, 223, 1, 45, 34, 78, 99};
    int n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
    int i = 0;

    MergeSort(A, n);

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d\n", A[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

--- LATEST EDIT ---

The new code, with modifications in Merge, works as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int Merge(int left[], int right[], int nL, int nR, int A[])
{
    int n = nL + nR;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for ( k = 0; k < n; k++ )
    {
        if(j >= nR || (i < nL && left[i] <= right[j]))
        {
            A[k] = left[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            A[k] = right[j];
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }

    return;
}

void MergeSort(int A[], int n)
{
    int mid = n/2;
    int left[mid], right[n - mid];
    int i;

    if(n<=1) return;

    for ( i = 0; i < mid; i++ )
        left[i] = A[i];
    for ( i = 0; i < n - mid; i++ )
        right[i] = A[i + mid];

    int nL = sizeof(left)/sizeof(left[0]);
    int nR = sizeof(right)/sizeof(right[0]);

    MergeSort(left, nL);
    MergeSort(right, nR);
    Merge(left, right, nL, nR, A);
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = {98, 5, 6, 78, 223, 1, 45, 34, 78, 99};
    int n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
    int i = 0;

    MergeSort(A, n);

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d\n", A[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to chqrlie and others for all the effort! :)

Comment: Please include the error message.

Comment: "MergeSort.exe has stopped working"

Comment: Quick one: Try changing the order of function so they are in the order: Merge, Mergesort, Main

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but the error's still showing :/

Comment: I have corrected sizeof(), and MergeSort(A, n), but still the run error persists! :/

Comment: This is clearly a console executable. Run it under `cmd` and tell us what this says. It may show a more descriptive error message.

Comment: What did you find out when you debugged it?  Which line raises the error?

Comment: No error  now, but it still doesn't sort the array.

Comment: You still do not pass `A` to the `Merge` function and did not fix it according to my other indications: change the test to `if(j >= nR || (i < nL && left[i] <= right[j]))` and also increment `k` in the loop.

Comment: Sorry for not editing, I'm kinda new at this. Have edited as you requested again, still doesn't work!

Comment: Saw your edited comment just now, it works! Thanks for all your effort! :)

Comment: For readability and style, you should write `int nL = mid;` and `int nR = n - mid;` instead of the `sizeof` computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems...

Most importantly, you use `sizeof` to get the number of elements in an array.
This only works for type `char` and similar.  For any larger types, you need to divide the size in bytes by the size of the element:

```
n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
```

The same fix is needed in the `MergeSort` function, but it would be simpler to have local variables for the sizes of the left and right halves computed before you instantiate the arrays.

Why do you store the return value of `MergeSort` in `A[n]` ?  Not only is `A[n]` out of bounds, but the assignment serves no purpose and the argument `A[n]` is bogus too.  The return type for `MergeSort` should be `void` anyway.  This line should read:

```
MergeSort(A, n);
```

In function `MergeSort` your initialization loop for the right half is incorrect:

```
for ( i = mid; i < n; i++ )
    right[i] = A[i];
```

It should be:

```
for ( i = mid; i < n; i++ )
    right[i - mid] = A[i];
```

The merge phase is incorrect too: you should pass `A` as an argument, not make it a local variable. `mid` is not a meaningful argument, the `left` and `right` arrays are separate, you should not offset the indices in `right` by `mid`. You should also test if the `left` or `right` halves have been exhausted before comparing the leftmost remaining elements.  You currently get undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = sizeof(A);
```

This will give `n` as `40` , thus `A[n]` is out of bounds.

In Function `int MergeSort`

```
for ( i = mid; i < n; i++ )
    right[i] = A[i];
```

So here array `right` indexing starts with `index=mid` (Array indexing starts with `0` ).

And in function `int Merge`

```
    int n = nL + nR;
int i, j, k = 0;    //i and j not initialized .
int A[n];

for ( k = 0; k < n; k++ )
{
    if( left[i] <= right[mid + j] )  // Used here. What i and j have ?
    {
        A[k] = left[i];
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        A[k] = right[mid + j];
        j = j + 1;
    }
```

In this function `i` `j` are not initialized and used as array index.Thus one more reason to give error.

Comment: I have inserted the edited code in my original query.

Comment: @user5123971 Please from next time post your related code as it is  :). Good luck !!